# Compare two date time to check whether date is active PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have one datetime in database which is saved in datetime format such as

**2019-09-23 06:00:00**
now i want to compare whether this datetime is greater than current datetime so as to check whether this record is of past or active for that i am doing something like this:

```
            $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $scheduleDate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($tableData->start));
            if($scheduleDate < $currentDate)
            {
                echo "active";
            }
            else{
                echo "Inactive";
            }
```

> This is database datetime :

2020-04-03 06:15:00

> This is current datetime :

2020-04-03 17:50:00

Now i'm getting active but the my database datetime is older because it is of morning,

Comment: There's no reason to use `date` here, just set `$currentDate = time();` and `$scheduleDate = strtotime($tableData->start);`

Comment: Doing this is creating mismatch of date time format : scheduleDate is 2020-04-03 06:15:00, currentDate  is 1585917258

Comment: This is working $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: And what's your question? What **exactly** is not working with that given code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set your default time zone
eg: date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

then use below code

```
$currentdate1=strtotime($currentDate);
$scheduleDate1=strtotime($scheduleDate);
if($currentdate1 < $scheduleDate1) 
{ 
echo "active"; 
}else
{ 
echo "Inactive";
}
```

Comment: use $currentdate1=strtotime($currentDate); $scheduleDate1=strtotime($scheduleDate);        if($currentdate1 < $scheduleDate1) { echo "active";
            }
            else{
                echo "Inactive";
            }